# Android6 Приложение не всегда видит интернет

Tags: android

Есть служба, которая периодически обращается на сайт за настройками. Загружает json файл.
На Android 4.4 и 5.0 работала отлично (На телефонах Samsung S4mini и LG Nexus5).
После обновления на Android6 телефона LG Nexus5 служба видит инет периодами. Может инет быть несколько минут, а потом пару часов нет. При этом я могу лазить в интернете через Chrome.
Проверку на наличие инета осуществляю функциями

```
private boolean isWiFiInetPresent() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  return cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

и

```
private boolean isMobileInetPresent() {
    boolean bRes=false; 
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo activeNetwork=cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      if (activeNetwork!=null) {
          if (activeNetwork.getType()==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
              if (activeNetwork.isConnected()) bRes=true; //Есть инет
          }
      }
    return bRes;
}
```

Пробовал загружать контент не проверяя наличие инета, ошибка по таймауту. В чем может быть причина? Может их хваленая функция сохранения энергии Doze. Но остальные приложения при этом работают.

Comment: Если просто пытаюсь получить данные, не проверяя наличие инета: IOException: failed to connect to al2sm.ddns.net/78.41.183.131 (port 443): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out). При этом в это же время есть инет на телефоне через Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена!!! Копал я в правильном направлении.
Помогла статья: [Android 6.0: Doze Mode, App Standby, Runtime Permissions](https://habrahabr.ru/post/269491/)
Вариант решения добавить приложение в настройках Settings > Battery > Battery Optimization ручками или программно.

Код для программного включения:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String packageName = getPackageName();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
       intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
}   
else {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
}
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Не забудьте дать REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS premission в вашем AndroidManifest.xml